# Why does make ignore escape sequence if the output is piped

Tags: pipe, make, binary-files, escape-characters

In a Makefile, I want to print a byte represented as a hexadecimal number and pass it to STDIN of another program. For some reason, it doesn't work:

```
without-pipe:
    @printf '\x66\x6f\x6f'

with-bash-and-pipe:
    @/bin/bash -c "printf '\x66\x6f\x6f' | cat"

with-pipe:
    @printf '\x66\x6f\x6f' | cat
```

Running this file produces:

```
$ make without-pipe 
foo

$ make with-bash-and-pipe 
foo

$ make with-pipe 
\x66\x6f\x6f
```

What feature of `make` am I missing and what is the proper way to make the last target produce the same output. The one `with-bash-and-pipe` is a sort of workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Note: my testbed is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.</sub>

---

Few steps are required to understand the behavior.

#### 1. Make is somewhat smart

It looks like `make` determines if a shell is required. I did

```
strace -f -e execve make without-pipe
```

and the part of the output was:

```
[pid 17526] execve("/usr/local/sbin/printf", ["printf", "\\x66\\x6f\\x6f"], 0x5569b5a5b440 /* 67 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 17526] execve("/usr/local/bin/printf", ["printf", "\\x66\\x6f\\x6f"], 0x5569b5a5b440 /* 67 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 17526] execve("/usr/sbin/printf", ["printf", "\\x66\\x6f\\x6f"], 0x5569b5a5b440 /* 67 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid 17526] execve("/usr/bin/printf", ["printf", "\\x66\\x6f\\x6f"], 0x5569b5a5b440 /* 67 vars */) = 0
```

So in this case `make` just probes possible locations of `printf` (according to `$PATH`) until the tool is found.

The behavior is different in the last case. This command

```
strace -f -e execve make with-pipe
```

yields (among other lines)

```
[pid 17592] execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "-c", "printf '\\x66\\x6f\\x6f' | cat"], 0x561465476440 /* 67 vars */) = 0
```

The tool is smart enough to tell you want to run a pipe. If you do, a shell is used. The shell is `sh`.

#### 2. The three cases use different `printf` implementations

- As shown above, `make without-pipe` uses `printf` executable available in the OS.
- `printf` is a builtin in bash (confirm with `type -a printf`), so `make with-bash-and-pipe` uses the builtin from bash.
- `printf` is also a builtin in sh (confirm with `(unset PATH; printf 'printf works\n'; ls)`; if it wasn't a builtin, sh couldn't find the executable like it cannot find `ls`), so `make with-pipe` uses the builtin from sh.

#### 3. `printf` is not required to understand `\x66` and such

[POSIX specification of `printf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) says:

> The *format* operand shall be used as the format string described in XBD [File Format Notation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap05.html#tag_05) with the following exceptions:
>
> […]

Neither of the two linked documents says `\xHH` and such must be special. I'm not sure if the specification explicitly allows them to be special, but the fact is they are special for some `printf`-s in the question.

But not for the `printf` builtin in sh.

---

> what is the proper way to make the last target produce the same output? The one `with-bash-and-pipe` is a sort of workaround.

You can make sure `printf` you run is not a builtin by specifying its full path:

```
/usr/bin/printf '\x66\x6f\x6f' | cat
```

however this requires you to know the path beforehand. To fix this issue you can use `env`:

```
env printf '\x66\x6f\x6f' | cat
```

`env` will run the executable found in `$PATH`. You can expect `env` to be present because it's required by POSIX.

On the other hand in general you can't be sure any `printf` executable (builtin or not) does support `\xHH` in the first place. Therefore the real fix is to rewrite your format string so it's properly understood by all POSIX-compliant implementations of `printf`. This seems useful:

> In addition to the escape sequences shown in XBD File Format Notation ( `\\`, `\a`, `\b`, `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\v` ), `\ddd`, where *ddd* is a one, two, or three-digit octal number, shall be written as a byte with the numeric value specified by the octal number.

Example:

```
printf '\146\157\157'
```

This approach works in all three cases.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive explanation.

The only remaining question is, is there a portable way to print a byte from the hexadecimal (or decimal) representation which doesn't require a lot of extra dependencies.